# Query to get product details and associated product image

Tags: mysql

I made a query from which i get product and its images . The query is working fine in cases in which a product has images . But it does not gets the products which does not have images . How can we make this query in such a way that the products which don't have a image is fetched too and a default image is used in that case for all of those products ? The query is

```
SELECT u.f_name,
       u.l_name,
       u.contact,
       u.user_id,
       u.address,
       u.city,
       u.org_name,
       u.website,
       p.id AS product_id,
       p.name AS product_name,
       p.price AS product_price,
       p.quantity AS product_quantity,
       p.description AS description,
       g.photo_url AS product_image
FROM user_profile u,
     product p,
     gallery g
WHERE p.category_id='1'
  AND p.subcategory_id='2'
  AND p.seller_id=u.user_id
  AND g.main_id=p.id
  AND g.type_id='2'
GROUP BY p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.f_name,
       u.l_name,
       u.contact,
       u.user_id,
       u.address,
       u.city,
       u.org_name,
       u.website,
       p.id AS product_id,
       p.name AS product_name,
       p.price AS product_price,
       p.quantity AS product_quantity,
       p.description AS description,
       CASE WHEN g.photo_url IS NULL THEN 'some_default_url'  ELSE g.photo_url END AS product_image
FROM user_profile u 
RIGHT JOIN
     product p ON p.seller_id=u.user_id 
JOIN
     gallery g ON g.main_id=p.id
  AND p.category_id='1'
  AND p.subcategory_id='2'
  AND g.type_id='2'
GROUP BY p.name
```

You might want to put some aggregate functions on some columns for more controllable results.

For a default image

```
CASE WHEN g.photo_url IS NULL THEN 'some_default_url' END AS product_image
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68294/discussion-between-mihai-and-user1001176).

Comment: @user1001176 Where is table product?

Comment: Please Check now . it was too large to put there

Comment: @user1001176 You can only JOIN these table through the product table just create it and add a few rows/

Comment: I added the product table

Comment: @user1001176 You forgot the fiddle.. )

Comment: @user1001176 Here is an attempt simplified because all those conditions didnt match the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b80bb/16

Comment: Now its getting the image as my old query did but not getting the products i wanted :( with the custom default image

Comment: @user1001176 Just add those conditions back I removed it in the fiddle

Comment: When u put back those conditions . Then its not considering the sub category and categtory id and showing me all products from all categories

Comment: @Put them back in a WHERE clause